# insert javascript variable into a hidden html form field onsubmit and before it get's received by the form target

Tags: javascript, forms, variables, paypal, onsubmit

So I have an html form and some JavaScript to check the contents.

I want to insert a value into one of the hidden fields BEFORE the form contents reach the target.

Normally the form would submit this data:

Amount: 9
Name: John Doe
Employer: Sears
Occupation: Clerk
Self Employed: no

All of the above input fields are text.

It all works fine except we want to take the values of the last 2 fields and append them together in the  to submit the following:

9, John Doe, Sears Clerk No, Clerk, no

This is a PayPal form so the actual fields are:

```
<form method="post" name="donationform" id="donationform" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" onsubmit="this.target='paypal'; return ChkInputs(this);">

<input name="amount" type="text" id="amount" value="" size="43" />
<input name="os0" type="text" size="43" id="os0" value="">
<input name="os1" type="text" id="os1" size="43" value="">
<input name="os2" type="text" size="43" id="os2" value="">
<input name="os3" type="text" size="43" id="os3" value="">


<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="company">
<input type="hidden" name="tax" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Donor" />
<input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Employer">
<input type="hidden" name="on2" value="Occupation">
<input type="hidden" name="on3" value="Self Employer">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.website.com"><!-- return URL -->
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-DonationsBF">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="emailgmail.com"><!-- Business name-->
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick"><!-- was buy it now -->
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2"><!-- prompt for an address, and require one -->
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1"><!-- hide the text box and the prompt -->
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD"><!-- currency is USD -->
```

I've been trying the make some kind of JavaScript that will take the values of os1, os2, and os3 and add them together (just textually) and then insert that text value back into the value that is passed along with the form for os1... something like os1 = os1 + os2 + os3

Been at it for hours and can't seem to get it to work.

I can get it to pass static values and to omit the values, but can't get it to do it dynamically from a JavaScript variable.

Could someone post some easy and simple code to do this?

Basically I need JavaScript that will do this:

```
<input name="os1" type="text" id="os1" size="43" value="----PUT A NEW VALUE HERE----">
```

or change the form to a differnt id then pass a hidden field with the required id for PayPal:

```
<input name="os1a" type="text" id="os1a" size="43" value="">

<input name="os1" type="hidden" id="os1" size="43" value="---- os1a + os2 + os3 ----">
```

I just can't seem to get it inside the value in the hidden field from an onsubmit action/event.

Thanks in advance for any help provided!

Comment: So make a function, get the values, convert the strings to numbers, add them together, and put the value back into the textbox.

Comment: you just try jquery post methods

Comment: @AnandSomasekhar and where is the jQuery tag?

Answer (score 0):

Try this idea

```
$("button").click(function(){
  var ab1=$("#idname1").val() //we take the value from text box1
  var ab2=$("#idname2").val() //we take the value from text box2

  //suppose a hidden text box with id hidden_val

   var content = ab1+','+ab2;
   $('#hidden_val').val(content);
});
```

this is only a demo

Comment: I must be really stupid but I just need to know how to put the a variable inside the value"" attribute... I know how to make a variable and add two variables already, but how does it get back into the id="os1" name="os1" value="???????????" attribute?

Comment: hello friend     $('#os1').val(content);     this only needed in jQuery to assign value to a textbox